# Which Hadith relate to Nationalism and Tribalism?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Can you provide me some hadith regarding [Nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism) and [Tribalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribalism)?

Comment: As both go against the rules of Islam I suppose you mean ahadith which include quotes of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Supporting tribalism is haram in Islam**. The prophet (saw) compared it to the acts of Jahiliyyah. The following hadiths shed some light on this matter:

It was narrated by Abu Hurairah that the Messenger of Allah (saw) said:

> “Whoever fights under a banner of folly, supporting tribalism, or
> getting angry for the sake of tribalism, he dies in a state of
> ignorance.”
>
> Grade: Sahih,  Reference: Sunan Ibn Majah 3948

It was narrated that Jundab bin 'Abdullah said:

> "The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: 'Whoever fights for a cause that
> is not clear, advocating tribalism, getting angry for the sake of
> tribalism, then he has died a death of Jahiliyyah.'"
>
> Grade: Sahih,  Reference: Sunan an-Nasa'i 4115